# Multilanguage CakePHP not working on select change

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration, cakephp-2.0, multilingual

In my website I implemented multilanguage option. It works when I change `Configure::wirte('Config.language', 'eng');` in core.php file, but when I try to do this with javascript it's not working. I have an AJAX call executed every time I change select and that part works, also I have php function:

```
public function changeLanguage() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    Configure::write("Config.language", $this->params['lang']);
    debug(Configure::read("Config.language"));
}
```

which is supposed to change language in configuration, and it does becuase it shows in that debug, but on the front page when I display the language config, it shows that it's null for some reason. And also I tried to load language config in all controllers, but it only works when I prewrite the language like this:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
$locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
if ($locale && file_exists(APP . 'View' . DS . $locale . DS . $this->viewPath . DS . $this->view . $this->ext)) {
    $this->viewPath = $locale . DS . $this->viewPath;
}
```

But without the Configure::write it doesn't work, but it should. And another thing, I added `window.location.reload()` after I receive code 200 from this function, so that the language could change, because php doesn't work without refreshing. Can you help?

Comment: Anything you write into the configuration is lost on the very next page load. I think you maybe meant to put it in the session instead?

Comment: Ok, so i tried to make session in javascript when select changes, but cakephp doesn't see it. When i try to display it in beforeFilter and my main site it shows null, when in javascript it shows the right value.

Comment: JavaScript sessions are stored entirely on the browser; PHP sessions are stored entirely on the server. They are completely unrelated. What you need for this is [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/development/sessions.html).